# No space left on device due to docker/cron

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have a basic server on google cloud that just runs a docker container via cron once every 30 minutes. I noticed that the docker command stopped working and I got an error saying

```
docker: Error response from daemon: no space left on device.
```

I then noticed that I got this error even when I trying to autocomplete in bash by typing `cd path/` and hitting `tab`. I figured out something was probably wrong with the storage so I tried `df -h` and it showed this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            860M     0  860M   0% /dev
tmpfs           175M   19M  157M  11% /run
/dev/sda1       9.7G  9.7G     0 100% /        
tmpfs           871M     0  871M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           871M     0  871M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           175M     0  175M   0% /run/user/1001
```

As you can see /dev/sda1 is 100% full for some reason. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I noticed there were several thousand exited docker containers so I removed this with this command:

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```

Now the storage usage is 61%, which is still too high.

Comment: common cause is some log is flooding in `/var/log` not always true , but better you can try to use `find /var -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -10` to see which are the top few files consuming the most of disk. if its something inside `/var/log` then you need to check which application is flooding the logs and fix that app. run this FOR `/var` ,`/home`

Comment: @ps That command's been running for 5+ minutes now. I suspect this may be the issue. Is there any way around that command?

Comment: you can do `ctrl + c` or from other terminal `kill` the `pid` of `find` command. Now you would have to manually visualize the size of the files.

Comment: also another common case, try to recall if someone has done some file transfer to the container recently and left the file as is ?

Comment: @ps The container is only run automatically by cron. No one else has access to the server except me. How should I visualize which folders are taking up space?

Comment: Do you delete your container after running it? Or are there lots of exited containers in `docker ps -a`? More details about what you are running in cron are needed.

Comment: you can try doing `ls -lrt |sort  -n -k5  |tail -10` to list largest 10 files in the dir. its a manual work as you aren't able to run `find` command. find out the largest few files and manually observe what is and who is writing into them

Comment: @BMitch Yes there several hundred exited containers. I run the container in docker with just the run command

Comment: @Bmitch check my last edit

Comment: Use `du` to find out where all the junk is, or a [disk space visualization tool](https://alternativeto.net/software/daisydisk/?platform=linux). To get started here find something, *anything*, you can delete to free up some space. An old log file. A downloaded installer. Whatever. Just get yourself some space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running containers that you do not need to keep in a stopped state, it's a good practice to use `docker run --rm ...` to automatically cleanup the stopped container.

If the container generates volumes, visible in `docker volume ls`, you'll likely want to clean these once the data is no longer needed. with the `--rm` flag on run, anonymous volumes (which appear as a long unique id) will be automatically deleted.

Docker also provides the command:

```
docker system prune
```

which you can automate to cleanup images, containers, networks, and even volumes. Note that you should take time to understand what this command does before running it, and especially before automating it. When scripting this command, you can use the `-f` flag to bypass the prompt.

Before running a prune, you can check:

```
docker system df
```

to see how much disk is being used by each component, and each component has it's own prune command, e.g. `docker container prune` and `docker volume prune`, should you want to clean just one area.

For more details on the prune command, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/